# how to "Each do |article|" but after every n-articles it has to start in a new row(foundation)

Tags: ruby, css, zurb-foundation, ruby-on-rails-5

I got this Rails blogs app and for the **indexpage** where the **articles** are posted it shows a **short** version of the article.

```
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

  <%= render 'layouts/topbar' %>

<div class="contentnews">
  <%= render 'layouts/bannerad' %>
    <div class="row">
      <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
        <%= link_to 'Nieuws toevoegen', new_article_path, :class => "button ala" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <%= render 'overview' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The overview-partial :

```
   <div class="articlebox ">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <% @articles.reverse_each do |article| %>
        <div class="articlebox2">
        <div class="articleindex">
          <%= link_to article.title, article %>
        </div>
        <div class="articlebody">
          <%= article.short.to_s.html_safe %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that this way all the articles end up in one row. I want it to show the short articles inline on the page and after every two or three article it has to start in a new row with again two or three short articles.

Anybody got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to create a row every n-elements. With foundation just wrap all the elements in a row, and give them columns class:

```
<div class="articlebox">
<div class="large-4 columns">
  <div class="row"> <!-- Wrap in  a row -->
    <% @articles.reverse_each do |article| %>
      <div class="articlebox2 large-6 columns"> <!-- Give a column and width class here -->
         ...
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So you can nesting grids with foundation, and creating new rows is not necessary, foundation will just wrap if the elements exceeds the grid.

If you actually really want to create rows, you can have a look at the method `each_with_index` [API](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) and then insert row elements `if index % 2 == 0`. But this is unnecessary complexity.